# how can i pass user information from loginpage to HomePage?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

> ```
> Error An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'User.Picture'
> ```

How can I pass user information from loginpage to HomePage? error on line `PictureImage.Source = User.Picture;`

**HomePage.xaml**

```
public partial class HomePage : ContentPage
    {
        public HomePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
             
            PictureImage.Source = User.Picture;
             IdLabel.Text = User.ID;
           NameLabel.Text = User.Name;
            ....
         }
}
```

**LoginPage.xaml.cs** here user can login using there google email and password. if no errors than run OnAuthCompleted method. In this method i am getting user information and going to homepage.

```
async void OnAuthCompleted(object sender, AuthenticatorCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var authenticator = sender as OAuth2Authenticator;
    if (authenticator != null)
    {
        authenticator.Completed -= OnAuthCompleted;
        authenticator.Error -= OnAuthError;
    }

    User user = null;
    if (e.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        // If the user is authenticated, request their basic user data from Google
        // UserInfoUrl = https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo
        var request = new OAuth2Request("GET", new Uri(Constants.UserInfoUrl), null, e.Account);
        var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
        if (response != null)
        {
            // Deserialize the data and store it in the account store
            // The users email address will be used to identify data in SimpleDB
            string userJson = await response.GetResponseTextAsync();
            user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(userJson);
        }

        if (user != null)
        {
            var route = $"{ nameof(HomePage)}";
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(route);
            //App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new HomePage());
        }

        await store.SaveAsync(account = e.Account, Constants.AppName);
        await DisplayAlert("Email address", user.Email, "OK");
    }
}//end of method
```

**user class** here ia m creating getter and setter for user information

```
    [JsonObject]
    public class User
    {
         [JsonProperty("id")]
         public string Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("verified_email")]
        public bool VerifiedEmail { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("given_name")]
        public string GivenName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("family_name")]
        public string FamilyName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("link")]
        public string Link { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("picture")]
        public string Picture { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("gender")]
        public string Gender { get; set; }
    }
```

**AuthenticationState class**

```
public class AuthenticationState
{
    public static OAuth2Authenticator Authenticator;
}
```

Comment: make `User` a property on your `App` class so that you can access it from anywhere in the app

Comment: could you show an example? I am trying to google how to access a class though my app but I am getting a bit confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a `User` property to your `App` class

```
public User CurrentUser { get; set; }
```

then anywhere in your app you can access it

```
if (App.Current.CurrentUser == null) 
{
    App.Current.CurrentUser = new User { ... };
}
```